# edit user menu item

Tags: menus, users

I want to add an "Edit User" link in my WordPress menu using the native Menu Manager.

Is there a URL that I can use that takes the user to their edit profile page?

I just don't know what to enter in the URL portion of a Custom Menu Item.

Comment: Note that plugin recommendations are off topic, I've removed the plugin suggestions part of your question so it isn't closed as off topic

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function `<?php get_edit_user_link( $user_id ) ?>`

Read more: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_edit_user_link

Best regards,

Comment: Thanks Quang.  That works great for adding the link to the template.  I am want to add the link through the Menu Manager.  I did try the php code in the menu item but it didn't work.

Comment: I did try the php code in the menu item but it didn't work.  I also tried using the php code in through a shortcode but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Such a link does exist and is already in the admin menu:

[image]

And again, in the admin toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of those two links.  I need to add a link in the front end website for users to use.

Comment: ooh does this have to link to the same page? Or are you expecting a frontend page for this?

Comment: @MicahK have you tried just copying the URL into a custom link in the nav menu? Making this show up as something you can drag into a nav menu is not a trivial ask, and very few people have the skills to figure that out, and the result will require a plugin to always be active or it won't work correctly

Comment: This site is using a prebuilt directory software/theme.  The system has a built in front end profile page that the user uses to edit their profile.  The front end profile page endpoint includes the users name so I cannot simply copy the edit url as it changes from user to user.  I will ask the developer on the theme to see if they can help me.  The more I think about this the more complicated it gets lol...  Thanks for your unput!

Comment: That further complicates things and was a pivotal piece of information missing in your question, Can you collect all these tidbits left in comments and edit them into your original question?